# Jenkins agent incorrect PATH environment variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

I'm using a remote agent to build my project in Jenkins via SSH.
Although the correct `PATH` environment variable is available when SSH'ing to it with the same user, it's not available when Jenkins tries to use the agent for building.

With the pipelines DSL, I was able to add it to my environment at runtime.

```
environment {
    PATH = "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
}
```

But I want this location in the PATH variable at all time, without this configuration. Any pointers on how to configure this for my agent; whether it is in the Jenkins node configuration or on the machine itself?

Answer (score 2):

Just for anybody who is having the same issue.

When adding a new node in Jenkins, the master caches the environment variables of this node, but doesn't update it afterwards, to avoid breaking the configuration.
If you update the environment variables on the node itself, this changes won't be available for builds from the Jenkins master. You have to re-add the node or add environment variables in the configuration of the node.

Comment: do you have a source reference for this, or did you learn it by experimentation?

Comment: @RianSanderson I think I read it somewhere in documentation, but I'm not sure where exactly...